# Error: No group node for sub node: indexing.getDependencies

Tags: pipelines

Hi everyone: I am getting the following error on a Sitecore 8.2 update 2 instance.
The error is related to the *indexing.getDependencies Pipeline*.

This error wasn't happening on Sitecore 8.1.

The error says:

> Exception: Sitecore.Exceptions.InvalidStructureException
>   Message: No group node for sub node: indexing.getDependencies
>   Source: Sitecore.Kernel

Have any of you have a fix to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems I found the fix. I was upgrading a pipeline processor from a 8.1 instance to a 8.2 instance.

In 8.1 I was using castle windsor to inject a dependency into the custom processor, therefore I was using

> type="1" ref="Demo.Extensions.Pipelines.GetDatasourceDependencies,Demo.Extensions" resolve="true"
>   in the configuration.

In 8.2 as we know Sitecore now provides a dependency injector by default, I didn't updated this processor configuration to use that. Anyway the fix was to change the processor to:

> type="Demo.Extensions.Pipelines.GetDatasourceDependencies,Demo.Extensions" resolve="true"

I hope this helps to solve any future problem with a similar case.